# ReactJS - Filter Nested Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, filter

So I am trying to set up a filter on nested array of objects. The thing is the filter is object. 
I just got the empty result.
Data sample:

```
obj:[
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "purpose": {
        "label": "Purpose",
        "type": "choice",
        "value": {
            "select": "loremIpsum",
            "options": [
                {
                    "value": "loremIpsum",
                    "text": "loremIpsum"
                }
            ]
        },
        "filter_groups": [
            "sd",
            "coll"
        ],
        "checklist_groups": {
            "sd": {
                "value": null,
                "comment": [],
                "is_disabled": false
            }
        }
    },
    "description": {
        "label": "Description",
        "type": "choice",
        "value": {
            "select": "loremIpsum",
            "options": [
                {
                    "value": "loremIpsum",
                    "text": "loremIpsum"
                }
            ]
        },
        "filter_groups": [
            "dv"
        ],
        "checklist_groups": {
            "sd": {
                "value": null,
                "comment": [],
                "is_disabled": false
            }
        }
    }
}
}
]
```

Try to do next:

```
const filterData = (e) => {
let filtredData = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(item => ({
        ...item,
        filter_groups: item.filter_groups
            .filter(child => child === e)
    }))
    
return filtredData;
}
```

But filter wants work, how filter by nested objects? 
I want to filter by **filter_groups**.
Do I have to use a regex to define the filter?

Comment: `Object.entries(obj)` returns an array [key, item]. You should destructure them in the map to filter the item. `.map(([key, item]) =>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not entirely clear what exactly you want as input and how your output should be formatted.  This version assumes you just want the `data` property of the first value of `obj`'s array, and turns it back into an object with the same sorts of keys you had in the original (such as `"purpose"` or `"description"`).

```js
const filterData = (e) => (data) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (data) .filter (([k, {filter_groups}]) => filter_groups .includes (e))
)

const obj = [{success: !0, data: {purpose: {label: "Purpose", type: "choice", value: {select: "loremIpsum", options: [{value: "loremIpsum", text: "loremIpsum"}]}, filter_groups: ["sd", "coll"], checklist_groups: {sd: {value: null, comment: [], is_disabled: !1}}}, description: {label: "Description", type: "choice", value: {select: "loremIpsum", options: [{value: "loremIpsum", text: "loremIpsum"}]}, filter_groups: ["dv"], checklist_groups: {sd: {value: null, comment: [], is_disabled: !1}}}}}]

console .log ('"sd": ', filterData ('sd') (obj [0] .data))
console .log ('"dv": ', filterData ('dv') (obj [0] .data))
console .log ('"foobar": ', filterData ('foobar') (obj [0] .data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Forgetting that outer shell, the trick here is that we convert it to an array of key-value entries with `Object .entries`, filter those entries by whether the `filter_groups` property of the value contains our target value, and convert the resulting array of entries back into an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a predicate method to perform a boolean test and determine it obj:[] is behaving live an array

````
```Array.isArray(arr); // true ```
````

Comment: if not registering array try creating a factor object and make it array like .